# How to get all objects, excluding ones that have records with same related field id value

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

Model `Model1` has ForeignKey field (`my_field`) to `Model2`. I want to retrieve all `Model1` without records that already have at least 1 record with same `my_field` value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get all distinct records from `Model1`, So this is how you can do it in django.

```
Model1.objects.all().distinct()
```

Hope this would answer your question.

Thanks

Comment: `distinct` simply removes duplicates, whereas I have to exclude such rows at all.